# Using the return values from one SQL statement in another SQL statement using SQL Magic in a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, sql, db2, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

I am working on a Jupyter Notebook on some standard DB2 table functions. I'd like to be able to refer to values returned from one SQL statement in other SQL statements. The syntax of the variable reference is getting me here. This is the code I use to get the values I want to use in later statements:

```
mgd_baseline = %sql select float(rows_read) rows_read \
    , float(rows_returned) rows_returned \
  from table(mon_get_database(-2)) as mgd
```

Then I would like to use it like this:

```
if mgd_baseline[0].rows_read > 0 or mgd_baseline[0].rows_returned > 0:
    %sql select decimal((float(rows_read)-:mgd_baseline[0].rows_read/(float(rows_returned)-:mgd_baseline[0].rows_returned),10,0) read_eff \
    from table(mon_get_database(-2)) as mgd
```

But that fails with this error message:

```
(ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError) ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: SQLNumResultCols failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "," was found following "-?[0].rows_returned)".  Expected tokens may include:  ")".  SQLSTATE=42601\r SQLCODE=-104 [SQL: 'select decimal((float(rows_read)-?[0].rows_read/(float(rows_returned)-?[0].rows_returned),10,0) read_eff     from table(mon_get_database(-2)) as mgd'] [parameters: ([(61959.0, 3219.0)], [(61959.0, 3219.0)])]
```

It looks to me like the sql magic is not passing on the value the way I would expect it to. It looks like it is considering the end of the host variable name the opening square bracket. I am not familiar enough with python to know what notation I can use to make it work.

I know I can do this as a workaround:

```
if mgd_baseline[0].rows_read > 0 or mgd_baseline[0].rows_returned > 0:
    bl_rows_read=mgd_baseline[0].rows_read
    bl_rows_returned=mgd_baseline[0].rows_returned
    read_eff=%sql select decimal((float(rows_read)-:bl_rows_read)/(float(rows_returned)-:bl_rows_returned),16,2) read_eff \
    from table(mon_get_database(-2)) as mgd
```

Due to some future plans, I would prefer to not have to do the additional assignment.

Is there any way to use those values (mgd_baseline[0].rows_read, mgd_baseline[0].rows_returned) directly in my sql magic sql statement without reassigning them?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It's not using host variables (generic compilation with different values for better package cache use), but for this particular application I don't particularly care if they're treated as host variables. Here is what works:

```
if mgd_baseline[0].rows_read > 0 or mgd_baseline[0].rows_written > 0:
    read_eff=%sql select decimal((float(rows_read)-{mgd_baseline[0].rows_read})/(float(rows_returned)-{mgd_baseline[0].rows_returned}),16,2) read_eff \
    from table(mon_get_database(-2)) as mgd
```